# Why cannot python PIL show two images in one program

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Here is my code:

```
img = Image.open('data/img.jpg')
lb = Image.open('data/label.png')
img.show('img')
img.close()
lb.show('lb')
lb.close()
```

After running this program, the first image is successfully showed, but the second image will not be shown unless I comment the code associated with the first image. What is the cause of this problem.

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: You could temporarily append the images side-by-side and show the result if you replace lines 3-6 with this: `Image.fromarray(np.hstack((np.array(img),np.array(lb)))).show() `

Comment: @Goyo you run this program and two windows are opened to show two images?

Comment: Yes. I guess it might depend on the actual program used to show the image and how it is invoked. Note that you can customize that with the `command` keyword.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can multithread to display both at once:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

from PIL import Image
from threading import Thread

def display(im):
    im.show()

im1 = Image.open('1.jpg')
im2 = Image.open('2.jpg')
t1=Thread(target=display,args=(im1,))
t1.start()
t2=Thread(target=display,args=(im2,))
t2.start()
```

[image]

---

Or you can temporarily concatenate the images into one:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

im1 = Image.open('1.jpg')
im2 = Image.open('2.jpg')

Image.fromarray(np.hstack((np.array(im1),np.array(im2)))).show()
```

[image]

Comment: never thought about concatenation, that makes things so much easier, thanks!

Comment: @M.HosseinRahimi Pad the smaller one... https://stackoverflow.com/a/54706194/2836621

Answer (score 0):

t1.join()
t2.join()

to be included in the main file so as to display the images and not close them immediately

Comment: As it's currently written, your answer is unclear. Does this refer to the accepted answer? How should it be added and what would it do?