# create an image with border of certain width in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have used PIL

```
#back_color_width 

for x in range(w):
    for y in range(h):
        if x==0 or y==0 or x==w-1 or y==h-1 :
            pixels[x,y] = back_color
```

I need to add a border to the image with a width on all 4 sides of image

Comment: I know you use PIL, but it might be worth mentioning it in the title or in the tags

Comment: Why have you defaced your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need to change to make the border any number of px wide:

```
for x in range(w):
    for y in range(h):
        if (x<border_width
            or y<border_width 
            or x>w-border_width-1 
            or y>h-border_width-1):
            pixels[x,y] = (0,0,0)
```

`#other 3 boxes` and `#primary box` Doesn't make boxes but instead 3 points and 1 point respectively.

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend using PIL's built-in `expand()` function, which allows you to add a border of any colour and width to an image.

So, starting with this:

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image, ImageOps

# Open image
im = Image.open('start.png')

# Add border and save
bordered = ImageOps.expand(im, border=10, fill=(0,0,0))

bordered.save('result.png')
```

[image]

---

If you want different sized borders on the top/bottom from the left-right, give two widths:

```
bordered = ImageOps.expand(im, border=(10,50), fill=(0,0,0))
```

[image]

---

If you want different sized borders on all sides, give 4 widths:

```
bordered = ImageOps.expand(im, border=(10,40,80,120), fill=(0,0,0))
```

[image]

**Keywords**: PIL, Pillow, ImageOps, Python, border, bordering, border outside, add border, expand, pad, extent, image, image processing.

Comment: This is a good answer (vs the accepted answer) because you're adding pixels to the image rather than the original strategy of overwriting existing pixels. It'll scale better, so if the border is variable you won't erase your image with the border if it grows.

Comment: Thanks This is a good approach .But this approach would not be helpful for "me" while accessing the pixels.

Answer (score 1):

You are really close! You just need to change the first `if` statement. Right now you do have a border, but the border is 1 pixel wide on all sides. Maybe change to

```
if x<back_color_width or y<back_color_width or x > w+ back_color_width or y > w+back_color_width:
    pixel[x,y]=back_color
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you meant, I think the solution is the following:

```
import numpy as np

def create_border(img, width, color = np.array([0,0,0]) ):
    #color must be a np.array

    img_shape = img.shape
    upper_border = np.full((width, img_shape[1], 3), color) #for 3-channel image
    side_border = np.full((img_shape[0] + 2*width, width, 3), color)

    bordered = np.concatenate([upper_border, img, upper_border])        
    bordered = np.concatenate([side_border, bordered, side_border], axis=1)

    return bordered
```