# How to pad images to a specific size like 720*576 with a pixel value/border value?

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library, scikit-image

I have images of various sizes like 122*98, 98*65, 320*256, 620*540. How to make all images to a fixed size say 720*576 by padding them with border/some pixel value? Is there a generic way to do it which works for input images of any size? I tried some methods using PIL module, but didn't get a generic solution.

Comment: Can you share the code of what you tried? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are pretty tool-agnostic since you have tagged with **OpenCV**, **PIL/Pillow** and **skimage**, so I would suggest just using **ImageMagick** on the command line:

So, starting with these images as `1.png`, `2.png` and `3.png`:

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can make an output directory and put them all in the North-West corner of a magenta background:

```
mkdir output
magick mogrify -path output -background magenta -extent 720x576 [123].png
```

[image]

Or, put them all in the centre of a yellow background:

```
magick mogrify -path output -gravity center -background yellow  -extent 720x576 [123].png
```

[image]

Omit the `-path output` if you want the files overwritten in place.

Omit the word `magick` if running v6 or older.

---

If you specifically want to do it in Python, one way is to make a solid canvas of the correct size and padding colour that you want as an output image and then paste your image onto that canvas, either at top-left or centred using some simple maths.

Another option is PIL/Pillow's `ImageOps.expand()` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54706194/2836621).

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [cv2.remap()](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#cv2.remap) function. This function has a parameter that let's you define a constant border value. The Opencv tutorial at https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/da0/tutorial_remap.html should give you enough info to start. The if-block `ind == 0:` in the tutorial resizes the image by 50%. You should be able to use this to get the fixed size of 720x576.