# Python PIL - add text BEFORE image (on top of image NOT on the image)

Tags: python, text, python-imaging-library

How can I add text on top of an image (i.e NOT INSIDE the image)?

[image: see example]

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import ImageDraw 

img = Image.open("SAMPLE-IN.png")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
# font = ImageFont.truetype(<font-file>, <font-size>)
font = ImageFont.truetype("FONTS/arial.ttf", 36)
# draw.text((x, y),"Sample Text",(r,g,b))
draw.text((0,0),"Sample Text",(0,255,255),font=font)
img.save('sample-out.jpg')
```

Comment: Add a border like this... https://stackoverflow.com/a/54706194/2836621 then write in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create an image that is bigger than the original one, paste the first one and the text onto it, like this:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw, ImageOps
img = Image.open("SAMPLE-IN.png")
img = ImageOps.expand(img, border=10, fill=(255,255,255))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
font = ImageFont.truetype("FONTS/arial.ttf", 36)
draw.text((0,0),"Sample Text",(0,255,255),font=font)
img.save('sample-out.jpg')
```

Comment: Thank you good, sir.  I increased border to 45 and that's what I'm looking for:   
                                           
 `img = ImageOps.expand(img, border=45, fill=(255,255,255))`