# Image Processing Error: module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute 'ImageWin' and 'ImageDraw'

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing

My objective is to print an inner and outer border on my image.

The number of pixels for the outer border should be 20, and the number of pixels for the inner border should be 10. I'm not sure why `win = Image.ImageWin(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight())` does not work and also `img.ImageDraw(win)`:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageWin

img = Image.open("Canada.jpg")
win = Image.ImageWin(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight())
img.ImageDraw(win)
img.setDelay(1,15)   # setDelay(0) turns off animation

for row in range(0,20):
    for col in range (img.getWidth()):
        p = img.getPixel(col,row)

        newred = 0
        newgreen = 0
        newblue = 0

        newpixel = Image.Pixel(newred, newgreen, newblue)
        img.setPixel(col,row,newpixel)

for row in range(224,img.getHeight()):
    for col in range(img.getWidth()):
        p = img.getPixel(col, row)

        newred = 0
        newgreen = 0
        newblue = 0

        newpixel = Image.Pixel(newred, newgreen, newblue)

        img.setPixel(col, row, newpixel)


img.draw(win)
win.exitonclick()
```

I get this error:

> module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute 'ImageWin' and 'ImageDraw'

PS: I'm running this on Windows O.S.

Comment: what is your OS? are you using windodws?

Comment: Windows right now

Comment: If you are writing for loops with PIL/Pillow, you have probably gone wrong. This post should help you add a border... https://stackoverflow.com/a/54706194/2836621