# add a black space for an image in Python pillow

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I wish to expand an image, so I can write something at the black expanded space under the original image, but it doesn't work.
I can't expand a black space and add it to the image, neither can write at a specific place

I'm new to the Pillow library, can anyone help?

Comment: Could you add an example of what you are trying to get? Like an image and the expected output

Comment: You can make a space below your image like this... https://stackoverflow.com/a/54706194/2836621

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

- read the image
- create a new image (black by default) with the desired size
- get data of the input image and put it down on the new one

```
from PIL import Image

HEIGH_OF_THE_BLACK_AREA = 100

with Image.open('image.jpg') as im:        
    new_im = Image.new(im.mode, size = (im.size[0], im.size[1] + HEIGH_OF_THE_BLACK_AREA))

    new_im.putdata(im.getdata())

    new_im.save('out.jpg')
```

Comment: If the img is .png, u will get transparent instead of black, so its better to specify that color.

Comment: thanks Tibebes,
do you know how to write at a specific area ?

Comment: @HamzaM.S.Abazeed check [this page](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html)

Comment: you basically do `ImageDraw.Draw(new_im).text(position_to_write_on, "Test Text", fill=(255, 255, 255))`