# Augmenting PIL images with borders in Pytorch efficiently

Tags: python, image, pytorch, python-imaging-library

I am trying to classify images where some of the evaluation images have a border of one of the following two types: White rectangles or black circle.

I would therefore like to see if I can improve the performance of my model by randomly augmenting some of the training images with a border. The images are loaded as PIL images and I am using Pytorch.

At the moment, I have the following code:

```py
class BorderTransformer(torch.nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, black_p=0.05, white_p=0.01, white_border_prop=0.05):
    """
    Args:
      black_p (float): Probability of adding a black circle border
      white_p (float): Probability of adding a white rectangle border if
                       black circle border was not added
      white_border_prop (float): Proportion of white border to add in relation
                                 to img. If 0.1, will add a white border spanning
                                 10% of the image to each side.
    """
    super().__init__()
    self.white_p = white_p
    self.black_p = black_p
    assert white_border_prop < 0.5, "Can't add white border bigger than full image"
    self.white_border_prop = white_border_prop
    self.black_indices = None
    self.to_tensor = transforms.ToTensor()
    self.to_pil = transforms.ToPILImage()

  def white_square_border(self, img):
    """
    Args:
      img (PIL Image): Input image.

    Returns:
      PIL Image: White rectangle bordered image.
    """
    img_tensor = self.to_tensor(img).to(device)
    _, width, height = img_tensor.size()

    h_border = int(self.white_border_prop * width)
    v_border = int(self.white_border_prop * height)

    # Setting left, right, top, bottom border in that order
    img_tensor[:, :h_border, :] = 1.0
    img_tensor[:, width - h_border:, :] = 1.0
    img_tensor[:, :, :v_border] = 1.0
    img_tensor[:, :, height - v_border:] = 1.0

    return self.to_pil(img_tensor)

  def _compute_black_indices(self, dim):
    """
    Args:
      dim (int): Height and width of image

    Returns:
      None, but sets self.black_indices to tensor of size (3, dim, dim)
      where values are True outside the circle and False inside.
    """
    black_indices = torch.zeros([3, dim, dim], dtype=bool)
    center = torch.tensor([dim // 2, dim // 2])
    max_len = torch.tensor(dim**2.0)
    for x in range(dim):
      for y in range(dim):
        vec = center - torch.tensor([x, y])
        is_outside_circle = (vec * vec).sum() > max_len
        black_indices[:, x, y] = is_outside_circle
    self.black_indices = black_indices

  def black_circle_border(self, img):
    """
    Args:
      img (PIL Image): Input image.

    Returns:
      PIL Image: Black circle bordered image.
    """
    img_tensor = self.to_tensor(img)
    _, width, height = img_tensor.size()
    if self.black_indices is None:
      self.black_indices = self._compute_black_indices(width)
    img_tensor[self.black_indices] = 0.0

    return self.to_pil(img_tensor)

  def forward(self, img):
    """
    Args:
      img (PIL Image): Input image.

    Returns:
      PIL Image: Bordered image.
    """
    if torch.rand(1) < self.black_p:
      return self.black_circle_border(img)
    elif torch.rand(1) < self.white_p:
      return self.white_square_border(img)
    return img
```

While this seems to work, it is also horrendously slow (making training take *3-4x* as long as without the augmention). I suspect it is due to the conversion to Tensor followed by the conversion back to PIL.

How would one write code that accomplishes something similar in an efficient manner?

Comment: I may be missing something, but why do you need this conversion to tensor then back to PIL ? I guess your data is eventually cast to a tensor to be put in a pytorch neural network, so what prevents you from applying this transform after the `toTensor` transformation in your `compose` ? Btw, you can remove the inheritance to `nn.Module` and replace `forward` with `__call__` to be able to use this object like any other pytorch transform

Comment: Thanks. The reason is that I have some transforms afterwards that require the image to be in PIL-format and not tensor. Thanks for the tip with `__call__` btw.

Comment: I don't know PyTorch at all, but if you are looking to add borders to images, this may help... https://stackoverflow.com/a/54706194/2836621

Comment: You could try to do the same operations without using `pytorch` but using `numpy` instead.