# Remove white space from an image using python

Tags: python, opencv

There are multiple images that have white spaces that I need to remove. Simply crop the image so as to get rid of the white spaces
Here's the code I tried so far (this is a result of search)

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('Sample.png')
img = img[:-5,:-5] 
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = 255*(gray < 128).astype(np.uint8)
gray = cv2.morphologyEx(gray, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, np.ones((2, 2), dtype=np.uint8))
coords = cv2.findNonZero(gray)
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(coords)
rect = img[y:y+h, x:x+w] 
cv2.imshow("Cropped", rect)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cv2.imwrite("Output.png", rect)
```

Here's the sample image

[image]

And this is the desired output

[image]

Comment: Please post your desired output.

Comment: The sample image has a scrollbar on the right. When cutting white space from the borders, the result will not look as expected.

Comment: The desired output still has white space on all 4 sides. How do you want the algorithm to distinguish between white space that shall be removed and white space that shall be kept?

Comment: @Thomas Weller I am just a beginner at using python and I am using stackoverflow to search for the topics. The general idea is to crop the image so as to fit the table with black pixels. As for the white space on left and right sides (consider it as padding)

Comment: hint: when you "find some code" (!), and it doesn't do what you want, and you ask others to do the work for you for free, *at least show that you tried* (and _what_ you tried) to solve the problem. you aren't new to programming or this site. questions like this show great disrespect to the people that _give their free time to help you_

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz I am a beginner at python and I already searched a lot before posting the question. Finally, in the question, I have put the nearest code that I thought is suitable for my case, but couldn't make changes to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is almost perfect. It just can't crop on the right side because of the scrollbar. And it does not consider some padding (which you liked according the comments).

The thing I removed is the topology modification.

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('cropwhitefromimage.png')
scrollbarright = 20
img = img[:, :-scrollbarright]
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = 255*(gray < 128).astype(np.uint8)
coords = cv2.findNonZero(gray)
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(coords)
padding = 10
rect = img[y-padding:y+h+padding, x-padding:x+w+padding]
cv2.imshow("Cropped", rect)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cv2.imwrite("cropwhitefromimage_result.png", rect)
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you very much. I tried to change the padding a little but didn't get the desired output. How can I change and widen the padding a little?

Comment: The padding probably becomes problematic if the white space is smaller than the desired padding. This would require making the image larger.

Comment: I have used this line `BASE_DIR = Path.cwd()` then `OUTPUT_DIR = BASE_DIR / 'Output'` and loop through images in specific folder and need to put the output in Output folder but I am stuck at this line `cv2.imwrite(OUTPUT_DIR / f'{str(filename)}', rect)`. The error says `Can't convert object to 'str' for 'filename'`

Comment: I have used this line that works `cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(OUTPUT_DIR, filename), rect) ` but I need to learn how use the pathlib to join the filename

Answer (score 1):

there could be issue with the result being negative with the pad. use max and min to be sure to extract the right content

```py
rect = cv_img[
    max(y-padding,0):min(y+h+padding,orig_h), 
    max(x-padding,0):min(x+w+padding,orig_w)
    ]
```