# how to expand a Python Pillow Image with different x and y border?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, editing

There is a function .expand() but it cannot expand each dimension differently. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: See https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-pillow-add-margin-expand-canvas/ (add_margin)

Comment: The answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54706194/2836621